# Where is gnome-terminal.desktop?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

Ive wanted to add `--maximize` option to its Exec command. But the file is just missing. Googling for it I've found that the file was there in the previous versions of gnome but there is no such `.desktop` file on my Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the package file list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/gnome-terminal/filelist), the file is now `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop`.

Comment: You are too fast.

Comment: oh yes the uppercase T, tried to find *term* but not Term